# if statement not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

I'm unable to identify the problem in this javascript code. I'm returning code 154, 155 and 1 from the server on certain logic. these numbers are returns but if statement is not working properly if it return a value which is true in if statement it still runs `else` (Default). Don't know why it cannot check if the value is same or not.

```
`$("#btnlogin").click(function (){

   // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "phpfiles/login.php";
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;    

    var vars = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "plain/text");

    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;


            if (return_data == "154"){
                $.Notification.notify('error','top left', 'Wrong Information', 'Username/Password is incorrect');
            }else if (return_data=== "155")
            {
                $.Notification.notify('error','top left', 'User Does not exist', 'This user Does not exist. Please Check and try again.');
            }
            else if (return_data == "1")
            {
                $.Notification.notify('success','top left', 'Success', '');
                GenToken();
            }else{
                alert();
            }
        };
    };
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request




});`
```

it always go down to else no matter if the condition is true or false. It is pointing towards this code

```
`<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    require_once("../class/class.login.php");
    $lh = new LoginHander;

    $lh->LogUserIn($username, $password, 'admin');
}
?>`
```

and this is calling this function

```
`    public function LogUserIn($username, $password)
    {
        $username = $this->es($username);
        $password = $this->es($password);
        $ip = $this->getClientIP();
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM admin WHERE username = ?";

        try{
            $query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array($username));
            $result = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->error($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->addlog($username, $ip);
        if(count($result) > 0)
        {
            header("Content-type: plain/text");
           $pass = $result[0]['password'];
           if(password_verify($password, $pass)){
               $this->SetVars($username);
               echo "1";
           }else{
                echo "154";
                exit();
           }
        }
        else
        {
           echo "155";
                exit();
        }
    }`
```

I don't know where is the problems i have tried `===` instead of `==` but it doesn't help. Please tell me where i made the mistake. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Did you verify the value of `return_data`? (`alert(return_data)` or `console.debug(return_data)`)

Comment: I'm sorry bro if I reduce anything, then I think you will not be able to generate the error to find a solution

Comment: yes it is working fine it returns 155 OR 154 OR 1

Comment: First, the HTTP response code `200` means `success`, don't use that to inform the user of errors. Second, it's good that you use `password_verify()` but the events `user not found` and `invalid password` really should be the same. The username-password combination is invalid. (That way an attacker won't be able to see whether the user `admin` does not exist (so he can stop trying to guess the password) or the user does exist (and it could make sense to continue guessing).)

Comment: Doing `console.log("-<" + return_data + ">-");` will help you check for stray whitespace characters around the returned code. The string `"154"` is **not** equal to the string `"154 "`.

Comment: Only thing I can think of then: try to remove the quotes. `" 1234" == 1234` but `" 1234" != "1234"` in javascript. Maybe you dropped in a space somewhere (eg before a `<?php`), those are hard to debug.

Comment: Thanx Arjan for the information.

Comment: @Pointy it was white space i got this response -<    154>- from the server now i'm use trim function to get rid of that space and now it is working fine. Thank you so much Pointy and everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can be debugged in the browser. Whenever one observes that a condition was not evaluated correctly, it is well advisable to check it up with a debugger.

```
return_data == "154"
```

is a non-strict check and will be evaluated to `true` even if their type is not the same. `154 == "154"` is `true`. On the other hand

```
return_data=== "155"
```

is a strict comparison. `155 === "155"` is `false`.

```
return_data == "1"
```

is another non-strict comparison.

Usually, these bugs occur from he situation where a strict comparison is being used on values which are similar, but not the same, or when white characters can be found at the start or the end of the value. It turned out that here that was the case.

Comment: yes, white space was there. That is the reason it wasn't validating.

Comment: @SharikShaikh, if you believe that this answers your question, then you might consider accepting it by clicking on the checkbox below the vote count to the left of the answer.